# Need help writing a mongoid query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

Here are my two models

```
class Customer
  field: name, type: String
  has_many :calls
end

class Call
  field: number, type: String
  field: call_time, type: DateTime
  belongs_to :customer
end
```

**My requirement:** For the above arrangement i.e., A `Customer` `has_many` `Calls` & a `Call` `belongs_to` a `Customer`. I would like to get the
List of customers ordered by the latest call of their calls.

Let me explain. Say, the database has the following data

```
Customer
John
     Calls
     987     /  10AM
     987     /   9AM
Jack
     Calls
     878     /  11AM
     878    /    6AM
Rohan
     Calls
     990     /  9AM
     990    /   8AM
```

My expected output would be

```
Jack
John
Rohan
```

Since the latest call was from Jack (@11AM), then John (@10AM), then Rohan (@9AM). Now how do I write such a query?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, if the `Call`'s are not embedded in the `Customer` document, the only solution is to load all of your customers and then sort them "manually" through `Enumerable#sort`, something like

```
Customers.where(some_criteria).sort_by { |c| c.calls.first.sort(call_time: -1) }
```

You might want to take a look at this: [Mongoid, how to order_by through a references_one association (and subsequent associations)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6452000/mongoid-how-to-order-by-through-a-references-one-association-and-subsequent-as)